# I try to sum all numbers in a txt file, putting two workable variables in one line and it returns 0. What's gone wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

I used 3 lines of codes which worked well. Then I try to contract them into one line, which I believe can be done by putting two variables together. But for some reason, the contracted codes only returned 0 instead of the actual sum that can be computed before. What's gone wrong in the contracted codes?

```
hand = open('xxxxxx.txt')
# This is a text file that contains many numbers in random positions
import re
num = re.findall('[0-9]+', hand.read())
# I used regular expression on variable 'num' to extract all numbers from the file and put them into a list
numi = [int(i) for i in num]
# I used variable 'numi' to convert all numbers in string form to integer form
print(sum(numi))
# Successfully printed out the sum of all integers


print(sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', hand.read())]))
# Here is the problem. I attempted to contract variables 'num' and 'numi' into one line of codes. But I only got 0 instead of the actual sum from it`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you execute all the code like I see up there, it is normal to get 0 because you didn't re-open the file after using it the first time, just re-open the file "hand" or leave the final line that you want to use and delete the three lines before it.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me -

```
hand = open('xxxxx.txt')
import re
print(sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', hand.read())]))
```

You have to close the file and reopen it before running the last line.